# How to get the information that was recorded in the ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I created a java application where login credentials are required to have access.
I recorded the information about username in `ArrayList`.

```
private void jBLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    String sql="select * from logins where username=? and password=? and idTypeLogin=?";
    try{
        pst=(PreparedStatement) conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, jTUser.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jPass.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jComboBoxTipoLogin.getSelectedItem().toString());

        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){

            String idTypeLogin= rs.getString("idTypeLogin"); 

            if (idTypeLogin.equals("Administrator")) {

                jTTaskAdmin ah = new jTTaskAdmin();
                ah.setVisible(true);

            }
             else {
                jTTaskTecnic eh = new jTTaskTecnic();
                eh.setVisible(true);

            }
            this.setVisible(false);
            }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Invalid");
              }
                //close();
            }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }



        List<String> loggedInUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
     loggedInUsers.add(jTUser.getText())

            List<String> t = loggedInUsers;   

           jTTasktecnic.recordVar=loggedInUsers.get(0);  
   }
```

[image]

And I add this code in second form

```
static String recordVar;
```

How can I do to get the information that was recorded in the array, but in another form. That is, I recorded the information in `ArrayList` in the Login form, now I want to get this information in another form.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Hey .. jUst try like this `yourList.get(0)` if the list having one element.. Check out for the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it Like this

> Form two

Declare A variable where you want to store ArrayList Item(*May be String or Int or something else*)

You can also declare it `static`.

But declare it Globally (Means at start of the class not inside method or something else)

> Form One

Store ArrayList Item in Variable of Form 2 `OnClick` of logIn button.

```
Form2 ob=new Form2();
ob.recordVar=arrayList.get(3);//it will access recordVar of Form2 3rd element of ArrayList for example
```

Or you can declare `Form2` variable `static` and acces it via class name.

Like this

```
Form2.recordVar=arrayList.get(3);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. what is recordVar? I tried the code that you gave very kindly, but gives error in recordVar.

Comment: Okay `recordVar` is variable you have to declare on second form you want to go,so declare it in second form as `String recordVar;`

Comment: Thanks again.I do that, but i made a system.out.println and recordVar is null only in 2nd form :S

Comment: Have you initialized variable in first form onclik? As suggested in my answer.

Comment: I think I do that. I edit my post, than you can check ;)

Comment: Scope of this `jTTaskTecnic eh = new jTTaskTecnic();` is limited to else block so declare at start of method and try.

Comment: Oh don't call me Sir :) Glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

define ArrayList as global so you can access it whenever you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply, how can I do that? I'm new in JAVA :S

Answer (score 0):

Let your method return the loggedInUsers and use it where you want. Change the method signature accordingly. Global variables are notorious. It is better to reduce the scope to where it is just required

```
private List<String> jBLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{
   // do samething
   return t
}
```